# Sensitivity (or responsitivity?) of an electrochemical sensor - Definition

Tags: sensor, education, sensitivity

I read a paper about an electrochemical sensor where there is the term sensitivity expressed in ampere. What is its definition? I found a IUPAC definition [here](https://media.iupac.org/publications/analytical_compendium/Cha10sec323.pdf), but the units are ampere/watt or volt/watt.

[image]

I read also the description of the tag sensitivity (or responsitivity), but online I didn't find this definition about a sensor which works in amperometric condition. I'm looking for a definition where there are also the possible units of measurement.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hello @EdV this is the reference: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/7348314?section=abstract

Comment: Is there any additional information you need on this? If not, I respectfully suggest giving one (or more) of the three answers an upvote and possibly pick one for the green checkmark. It is highly doubtful that any more answers will be forthcoming.

Comment: Hello @EdV, I am wondering if the author of the paper did a mistake when he expressed sensitivity in nA.

Comment: It is fairly common because the ordinary language usage facilitates this sort of thing misconception. But “high sensitivity” can mean low values or high values: it is ambiguous. Sensitivity as a slope is the current accepted term and it is distinct from detection limit, which is basically a measurement noise specification (e.g., a standard deviation) divided by the sensitivity. Then  low detection limit is better than a higher one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sensitivity, formally, is $$\frac{\partial \text{Output}}{\partial {\Theta}} $$

where \$ \Theta\$ is the parameter of interest.

This is generally the way sensitivity appears, thought the output can be specified different ways, such as the change in resistance of a sensor, or the resulting voltage change.

Answer (score 1):

Responsivity is a measure of the gain of the detector, output/incident ratio. If the output is current, measured in amps, and the input is radiation power, measured in watts, then the responsivity will have units of amps/watt. With a voltage output, it would be volts/watt.

Sensitivity sounds like it ought to be a measure of the smallest signal a detector can reliably sense. However, if it's given in units of amps, for a current output detector, then it's the output at the minimum detectable input level. It obviously needs scaling by the responsivity if it's to represent the minimum detectable input level itself.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT at bottom**:

Unfortunately, sensitivity has been used in several inconsistent ways over the years. In analytical chemistry, of which electrochemistry is a part, the definition of sensitivity is as per the IUPAC Gold book:

[image: IUPAC sensitivity definition]

So this is a responsivity, as the OP surmised and other answers stated. The units are those of the output response divided by those of the input variable. If the functional relationship is non-linear, then the sensitivity is simply the slope of the response curve, as expected.

Annoyingly, sensitivity is also used as a **deprecated** term for detection limit, however defined. This leads to confusion since high sensitivity then means low detection limit. In the case of the OP's Table 1, sensitivity is being used as a detection limit, but this says nothing about the dominant noises or whatever statistics may be involved, e.g., are false positives and false negatives being accounted for or only false positives? This usage should be entirely spurned.

Note: "PAC" is the abbreviation for the journal "Pure and Applied Chemistry", where IUPAC documents are published.

**Newly added**:
A couple of examples may help to illustrate the above. First, consider the paper by Salimi *et al*. (A. Salimi, R. Hallaj, B. Kavosi, B. Hagighi, "Highly sensitive and selective amperometric sensors for nanomolar detection of iodate and periodate based on glassy carbon electrode modified with iridium oxide nanoparticles", *Anal. Chim. Acta* **661** (2010) 28-34. In their abstract, the authors state that "amperometric determination of iodate and periodate yielded calibration curves with the following characteristics: linear dynamic range up to 100 and 80 µM, sensitivity of 140.0 and 150.6 nA/µM and detection limits of 5 and 36 nM, respectively." So sensitivity is being used correctly as a responsivity.

Second example: Giri *et al*. (A.K. Giri, C. Charan, A. Saha, V.K. Shahi, A. Baran, "An amperometric cholesterol biosensor with excellent sensitivity and limit of detection based on an enzyme-immobilized microtubular ZnO@ZnS heterostructure", *J. Materials Chemistry A*, **40** (2014) 16997-17004. In their abstract, the authors state that their electrode has "excellent amperometric cholesterol-sensing performance, with sensitivity 52.67 mA \$M^{-1} cm^{-2} \$, signal to noise (S/N) ratio = 15, and limit of detection (LOD) 0.02 mM with S/N = 3." So sensitivity is again being used correctly as a responsivity.

*There are many, many examples like this*. It makes no sense to just use current as a proxy for sensitivity because other factors are involved, e.g., noise and statistics considerations.